# Django update_or_create not updating but inserting instead

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am not able to update rows in django model when using update_or_create(). It will create a new row but not update it. I don't get any error after running this code in command line. I am sure I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what.

```
model.py

class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, unique=True)
    bites = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    imgs = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
```

```
.\manage.py shell
from status.models import Test
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
2020-02-10  2355975072768 939

d2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
2020-02-10  2355975072768 938

for model in d1.itertuples():
    model, created = Test.objects.update_or_create(date=model.date, bites=model.total_bytes, imgs=model.total_files, defaults={'date': model.date, 'bites':model.total_bytes, 'imgs':model.total_files })

database_sqlite3 output: 
1|2020-02-10|2355975072768|939

for model in d2.itertuples():
    model, created = Test.objects.update_or_create(date=model.date, bites=model.total_bytes, imgs=model.total_files, defaults={'date': model.date, 'bites':model.total_bytes, 'imgs':model.total_files })

database_sqlite3 output: 
1|2020-02-10|2355975072768|939
2|2020-02-10|2355975072768|938
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't update, as [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) first tries to get and update an object with the provided arguments and if it does not find something, it creates a new object. It is creating a new object, as it can't find an object in your database with the argument imgs=938.

You can just omit the `imgs` argument to allow the function to find an object with the provided `date` and `bites` arguments:

```
model, created = Test.objects.update_or_create(date=model.date, bites=model.total_bytes, defaults={'date': model.date, 'bites':model.total_bytes, 'imgs':model.total_files })
```

Comment: I did try with only date=model.date as my main aim is to update bytes and imgs by date, but it did not work. This still give me a new row in the database
```
model, created = Test.objects.update_or_create(date=model.date, bites=model.total_bytes, defaults={'date': model.date })
```

Comment: It would be better if you have an unique id for your .csv files, as date is not a good unique identifier. You could have more than one entry per date. What is the database_sqlite3 output when you tried only with date=model.date?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You meant: Test.objects.update_or_create(date=m.date, defaults={'bites':m.total_bytes, 'imgs':m.total_files }). This actually work! Thanks! I removed imgs and bites from defaults.